# Scrollbar not visible on android emulator

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, scrollbar

I am a newbie to android app development, i am using the ADT with eclipse.
I wrapped all the view components in a scrollbar but when i use the emulator preview i cannot see the scrollbar. The target is a 7inch WSVGA (Tablet).

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imageDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test_image_date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Clouds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/test_image" 
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imageDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test_image_description"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

No errors have been generated.
Cheers
Ciaran

Answer (score 3):

The scrollview will only be visible if you have enough content that would not fit on the entire screen. Seeing your xml it is possible that you don't have that much of content in the layout

Comment: No the TextView id/imageDescription is actually very long and is cut off at the end of the screen......

Comment: change layout_height of scrollview to wrap content and see if it works

Comment: tried but same, i wonder if has something to do with the emulator although the Graphic layout doesn't shoe scrollbar either, i a using Holo theme

Answer (score 0):

So ran this activity on a Samsung T3 8 inch tablet and the scroll worked fine, couldn't seem to get it on the emulator with a similar simulated device.